# blurred background when message appears

Tags: html, css

When i click on success button this message appears, The background becomes blurred. I need when i click on the close button the background of the body becomes normal. I really appreciate your help.

## CSS:

```
#card {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  width: 340px;
  margin: -5px 0 0 -400px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
}

#upper-side {
  padding: 2em;
  background-color: #3CB371;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
}

#checkmark {
  font-weight: lighter;
  fill: #fff;
  margin: -3.5em auto auto 20px;
}

#status {
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-top: -.2em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#lower-side {
  padding: 2em 2em 5em 2em;
  background: #F0F0F0;
  display: block;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}

#message {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin-top: -.5em;
  color: #757575;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

## HTML

```
{% if success %}
 <body style="filter: blur(2px);" > 
 <div id="messageContainer">
 <div id='card' class="animated fadeIn">
 <div id='upper-side'>
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
  <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
  <svg version="1.1" id="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve">
    <path d="M131.583,92.152l-0.026-0.041c-0.713-1.118-2.197-1.447-3.316-0.734l-31.782,20.257l-4.74-12.65
c-0.483-1.29-1.882-1.958-3.124-1.493l-0.045,0.017c-1.242,0.465-1.857,1.888-1.374,3.178l5.763,15.382
c0.131,0.351,0.334,0.65,0.579,0.898c0.028,0.029,0.06,0.052,0.089,0.08c0.08,0.073,0.159,0.147,0.246,0.209
c0.071,0.051,0.147,0.091,0.222,0.133c0.058,0.033,0.115,0.069,0.175,0.097c0.081,0.037,0.165,0.063,0.249,0.091
c0.065,0.022,0.128,0.047,0.195,0.063c0.079,0.019,0.159,0.026,0.239,0.037c0.074,0.01,0.147,0.024,0.221,0.027
c0.097,0.004,0.194-0.006,0.292-0.014c0.055-0.005,0.109-0.003,0.163-0.012c0.323-0.048,0.641-0.16,0.933-0.346l34.305-21.865
C131.967,94.755,132.296,93.271,131.583,92.152z" />
    <circle fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="109.486" cy="104.353" r="32.53" />
  </svg>
  <h3 id='status'>
  Success
 </h3>
</div>
<div id='lower-side'>
<p id='message'>
  Thank you for your interest in Neotic.
</p>
<div>
<a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right" onclick="$('#card').hide();">X</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: i found this proberty : <body style="filter: blur(2px);" >

I added to if success 
But i want to remove the blur when the message is closed

Comment: Then listen for a close event (be it a click on the close button or the blurry body) and remove the `blur` css property. Something like `document.body.addEventListener('click', function( event ){ if( event.target.id !== 'message' ){ document.body.style.filter = 'none'; /* (and other closing related matters like removing the message box, etc..) */ }});`

Comment: i am a beginner i don't know how to add it to html if you can help me

Comment: You must already have some code to close the message box, otherwise you might as well reload the page without the box or blur. In that closing code you simply need to add `body.style.filter = 'none'` to remove any blur effect on the body.

Comment: thank youuu it works 
but 

{% if success %}
<body id="overlay" style="filter: blur(2px);" >

 <div id="messageContainer"  >
</div>
  <div id='lower-side'>
    <p id='message'>
      Thank you for your interest in Neotic.
    </p>
   <div>
   <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right" onclick="$('#card').hide(); body.style.filter = 'none' ;">X</a>
  </div>
How to remove blur for message container ?